# Cannot make Connection to SQLite database Swift 3

Tags: swift, sqlite

i'm using [SQLite Library](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/tree/0.11.0) and in usage it says `let db = try Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")` i have sqlite database located in documents. but when i try to make connection it throw an error `call can throw but errors cannot be thrown out of a property initializer`

here's my code :

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

let db = try Connection("/Users/macbookpro/Documents/db.sqlite") //error
let categoryVC = CategoryViewController()
let UseFullVC = UseFullViewController()
let MapVC = MapViewController()
let EventVC = SearchResultOnlineVC()

@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Search"

    searchTextField.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

i also try to put connection in viewDidLoad but still doesn't work

what's wrong?

Comment: why cant you go with the FMDB, why using raw sqlite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Connection` initializer can throw an exception, you need to call it in a `do/catch` block.

So you should change the declaration to:

```
var db : Connection?
```

And initialize it in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
do{
    self.db = try Connection("/Users/macbookpro/Documents/db.sqlite")
} catch {
    print("Unable to create connection: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

let sharedInstance = DBModelManager()

class DBModelManager: NSObject {
  var database: Connection!

 class func getInstance() -> DBModelManager
 {
     if(sharedInstance.database == nil)
     {
         do{
             let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
             let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("dbname").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
             sharedInstance.database = try Connection(fileUrl.path)

         }catch{
             print("DB Error \(error)")
         }
     }
     return sharedInstance
  }
}
```

Call DB instance this way

```
try DBModelManager.getInstance().database!.prepare()
```